# Is there any name for this type of illustration?

Tags: style-identification

I was wondering if there is a name to refer to these type of illustrations? I'm particularly referring to the rounded-corner lines being used extensively to construct other elements of the illustration.

[image]

[Source](https://www.behance.net/gallery/37415235/Wordrow-Vocabulary-Game)

[image]

[Source](https://youtu.be/JQVmkDUkZT4?t=66)

[image]

[Source](https://youtu.be/X9otDixAtFw?t=69)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never heard of a specific name for the curved corners, generally it is used in flat design design though, so probably it is part of this last one.

Comment: Thanks, I just did a search for 'flat design' and I found a few tutorials explaining how to create 'rounded lines', but as you said none was referring to it with any specific name neither.